# Empty MySQL query results from subdomain

Tags: php, mysql, database, subdomain

I have a website (e.g. site.com) hosted on an apache server (Plesk VPS). phpMyAdmin is installed for administrating the MySQL database on the site. I used the "Copy Table" function in phpMyAdmin to copy the structure and properties of an existing table. I imported new data to the new table successfully.

I created a new subdomain (xx.site.com) and assigned its root directory to //httpdocs/new_site on the server. After copying the existing (working) php script which queries the old table for data

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE '$var' "); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($fetch)) {
echo  "$row[0] $row[1] $row[2] $row[3] $row[4] $row[5]";
};
```

and changing the tablename to the newly copied and populated table I am getting an empty results set. It's worth noting the php script executes normally, without error, and passes the empty result set back successfully which can be replaced with an echo of $var establishing the query is not empty / null.

The code to establish $var is:

```
$var = $_GET['var']; //takes the pass from URL 


if (empty($var)) 
   die;
```

How can I troubleshoot this? What clues should look for? What information would establish where the problem lies?

Comment: Do you get results when you run the query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: *Hm...* Whether it's a sub-domain or not, do you think it has anything to do with MySQL and not the way you're accessing the script?

Comment: A good place to start when a query is not giving you what you expect is to `echo` the query so you can see **exactly** what is being sent to the database. Try `echo "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE '$var' "` just before the `mysql_query` call. Often you will see the problem immediately when you see the query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! However, yes I get results normally when querying via phpmyadmin. And the script I copied from the original (site.com) is still up and functioning so I think MySQL is working normally.

Comment: Check the data is in the new table using PHPMyAdmin. Check that the mysql_connect statement did actually connect to the database, by testing the response and logging it. If you have time, replace all mysql accesses with equivalent mysqli or PDO calls :-)

Comment: You mention that you populated the table with **new** data - is it possible that your query simply isn't matching anything? Maybe everything's running correctly.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to the same database that you can see in phpMyAdmin too.

Comment: When I 

echo "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE '$var' "
I get:
Resource id #4

Comment: (Aside: it's not a bad first question! There's enough detail to get a selection of suggestions as to what to try. If I can offer a minor quibble, I'd advise getting to the point quickly - many questions add preambles like 'Please be nice', 'I am new to X', etc etc and they don't really add anything to the question. They generally get edited out by editors here too).

Comment: I did. It got trimmed. Sorry for n00b.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: The code establishing $var is:
'session_start();
 
$var = $_GET['var']; //takes the pass from URL 
 
 
if (empty($var)) 
   die; '

Comment: ^ Please edit that **in the question**, as requested. There's an edit link for this purpose; this saves new readers from having to scan the whole conversation history. Thanks `:)`.

Comment: It seems the "new" data I imported to the table was not correct. Thanks to Kryten for picking up on it and suggesting the fix. Also many thanks to everyone who jumped to the rescue so quickly. Looking forward to learning more here! I'll be adding this as the answer after the required 8hr n00b restriction has expired.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed a `%`

Change your query to this

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE '$var%'
```

If you put a `%` to the right of the `$var` it will match anything from left to right.

If you put a `%` to the left of the `$var` (`'%$var'`)it will match from right to left of the column `fieldname`

When you use `LIKE` operator you ***should*** indicate where to start searching. If you want exact match. Do like this

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname='$var'
```

EDIT

AS suggested by Fred -ii-,

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE '". $var ."&'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname='". $var ."'
```

Comment: The `%` is optional http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: It depends on what match(es) the OP is looking to get. Either with a `%` at either the beginning and/or end or without it.

Comment: All true @Fred-ii-, but if you use a `LIKE` operator without `%`, then that exact value must exists in the table, otherwise empty dataset is returned. IMHO, using `LIKE` without `%` is bad practice. That why i thought it was a miss by the OP since the opreator LIKE would suggest find matching rows LIKE .... Also, if the OP is looking for a match, the `=` is the correct way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I added the % as suggested. No change.

Comment: So try `WHERE fieldname = '$var'` @user3632998 or `WHERE fieldname = '". $var ."'`

Comment: Im no php developer but dont you need to wrap the $var with + to get the actual value? I just want to make sure its not looking for the value $var?

Comment: `WHERE fieldname = '". $var ."'` results in error 500
and
`WHERE fieldname = '". $var ."&'` results in response: Resource id #4

Comment: Can you replace $var with a hardcoded value that exists in the database? `WHERE fieldname='test'` Then you can determine if its mysql or a php problem. Note that you should use `%` not `&`

Comment: It seems the "new" data I imported to the table was not correct. Thanks to Kryten for picking up on it and suggesting the fix. Also many thanks to everyone who jumped to the rescue so quickly. Looking forward to learning more here! I'll be adding this as the answer after the required 8hr n00b restriction has expired.